# Spring scheduling interval configuration in Websphere 8

Tags: spring, websphere, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible to specify the fixed delay interval or the cron interval pattern through some custom properties when deployed on web sphere. Currently, in my configuration the fixed delay interval is specified on the application context xml file. However, this file will get packaged in an EAR and a change to interval would require application redeployment.

Here is my app context file:

```
<bean id="taskScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.TimerManagerTaskScheduler"> 
    <property name="timerManager" ref="timerManager" />
</bean>
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor">
    <property name="workManager" ref="workManager" />
</bean>

<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="taskScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="transactionProcessingService" method="processTransactions" fixed-delay="30000"/>
    <task:scheduled ref="transactionProcessingService" method="processOrderTransactions" fixed-delay="50000"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<util:properties />` tag for loading properties from files:

1. Move your values to some property file (for example `app.properties`)

   ```
   process_transactions=30000
   process_order_transactions=3000
   ```
2. load them via `properties` tag from `util` namespace (do not forget to [declare **util** namespace](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util))

   ```
   <util:properties id="appConfig" location="classpath:app.properties" />
   ```
3. set them using `${variable}`syntax:

   ```
   <task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="taskScheduler">
       <task:scheduled ... fixed-delay="${process_transactions}"/>
       <task:scheduled ... fixed-delay="${process_order_transactions}"/>
   </task:scheduled-tasks>
   ```

**EDIT.** As explained by @user320587 we can override application property value by using JVM Custom properties in Websphere (and avoid redeploiment):

> By using this along with the systemPropertiesModeName property
>   available in the PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer, we could avoid
>   redeployment. I have set the property values as part of JVM Custom
>   properties in Websphere and the substitution happens when the
>   application is started. So, to change the interval value, I can modify
>   the custom property value and restart the application.

Comment: How would this allow to avoid redeployment? It is not much better than keeping values in XML file. Editing files within deployed application is mainly a hack that will cause problems in future.

Comment: By using this along with the systemPropertiesModeName property available in the PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer, we could avoid redeployment. I have set the property values as part of JVM Custom properties in Websphere and the substitution happens when the application is started. So, to change the interval value, I can modify the custom property value and restart the application.

Comment: Thenk you user320587 for pointing this out. @fnt, now it is good for you?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in your application context

```
   <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
         <property name="location" value="classpath:sample.properties"/>
          <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
          <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
          <property name="order" value="0"/>
   </bean>
```

Your sample.properties file

```
process_transactions = 30000
processOrder_transactions = 3000
```

Replace the following with your code.

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="taskScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="transactionProcessingService" method="processTransactions" fixed-delay="${process_transactions}"/>
    <task:scheduled ref="transactionProcessingService" method="processOrderTransactions" fixed-delay="${processOrder_transactions}"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```